# Button gets hidden by an input field when the input field is focused

Tags: css, reactjs, button, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

So I have this code that enables me to show a button whenever some text is written in the textbox next to it. For that purpose, I use bootstrap and the `input-group-append` class. I had some problems before with it and I've managed to solve some of them but now I stumbled upon new undesired behavior. Namely, the text field should show a button next to it if something was written in this same text field. However, if I write something, the button won't pop up. If I defocus my text field, the button shows up. Focusing again i.e clicking on it, the button hides once again and it acts like this. This is the code that I use:

```js
<div className="input-group" style={{ position: "relative" }}>
<input
   type="text"
   className="form-control"
   placeholder="Recipient's username"
   aria-label="Recipient's username"
   aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
   onChange={onChange}
   />
{showAppend === true && (
<div
className="input-group-append"
style={{ position: "absolute", right: 0, zIndex: 2 }}
>
<span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
@example.com
</span>
</div>
)}
</div>
```

This is a working [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-grass-rqgmr?file=/src/App.js:658-1275) from CodeSandbox. You can try it out, type something, defocus -> the button is voila. Click on the input field again, the button disappears. Defocus again, voila again. The `onChange` function changes the value of `showAppend`.

So, how can I show this button on top of the `input` field? I tried adding `z-index` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my answer.

I have done it by `position: relative`.

```
<div className="input-group-append" style={{ position: "relative", right: 0, zIndex: 100 }} >
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer is solved my question, so did @Will Jenkins' comment.